# How to extract common properties of a flat list of objects and build a nested list of the rest of properties

Tags: c#, linq

The title is hard to explain so here I'll describe the best I can what I need to achieve based on what I have been given: I receive a flattened List such as the following:

```
{
    {
        "MediumDescription": "SMS to mobile phone",
        "CommunicationMediumCode": "SMS",
        "CommunicationGroupDescription": "SMS",
        "CommunicationMediumId": 5,
        "CommunicationGroupId": 18
    },
    {
        "MediumDescription": "Web with email notification",
        "CommunicationMediumCode": "WbEml",
        "CommunicationGroupDescription": "SMS",
        "CommunicationMediumId": 6,
        "CommunicationGroupId": 18
    },
    {
        "MediumDescription": "Web with SMS notification",
        "CommunicationMediumCode": "WbSMS",
        "CommunicationGroupDescription": "SMS",
        "CommunicationMediumId": 7,
        "CommunicationGroupId": 18
    }
}
```

As you can see there are some common properties: GroupId and its Description and the rest are the available Mediums for that GroupId but they are not grouped together. (I have removed some other properties for simplicity). With this information I need to build the following:

```
{
        "CommunicationGroupId": 18,
        "CommunicationGroupDescription": "SMS",
        [
            {
                "MediumDescription": "Web with SMS notification",
                "CommunicationMediumCode": "WbSMS",
                "CommunicationMediumId": 7,
            },
            {
                "MediumDescription": "Web with email notification",
                "CommunicationMediumCode": "WbEml",
                "CommunicationMediumId": 6,
            },
            {
                "MediumDescription": "SMS to mobile phone",
                "CommunicationMediumCode": "SMS",
                "CommunicationMediumId": 5,
            }
        ]
}
```

Here is what I believe the C# model should look like:

```
public class NewCommunicationPreference
    {
        public int CommunicationGroupId { get; set; }
        public string CommunicationGroupDescription { get; set; }
        public List<MediumModel> Mediums { get; set; }

    }
public class MediumModel
    {
        public string MediumDescription { get; set; }
        public string CommunicationMediumCode { get; set; }
        public int? CommunicationMediumId { get; set; }
    }
```

**Attempted**

With the following I can build the typed object but within this new type there is a List but I just don't know how to extract the properties for a common GroupId. How can I achieve my goal?

```
var groupedComms = result
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.CommunicationGroupId,
                g.CommunicationGroupDescription,
           
            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

***Thank you***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `result` is `IEnumerable<FlatListModel>`:

```cs
public class FlatListModel
{
    public int CommunicationGroupId { get; set; }
    public string CommunicationGroupDescription { get; set; }
    public string MediumDescription { get; set; }
    public string CommunicationMediumCode { get; set; }
    public int? CommunicationMediumId { get; set; }
}
```

, then

```cs
var groupedComms = result
    .GroupBy(
        flat => new { flat.CommunicationGroupId, flat.CommunicationGroupDescription },
        (key, list) => new NewCommunicationPreference {
            CommunicationGroupId = key.CommunicationGroupId,
            CommunicationGroupDescription = key.CommunicationGroupDescription,
            Mediums = list.Select(m => new MediumModel {
                CommunicationMediumId = m.CommunicationMediumId,
                CommunicationMediumCode = m.CommunicationMediumCode,
                MediumDescription = m.MediumDescription }
                ).ToList()
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```